# bufferCount(2,1) seems to be returning same value twice

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got an Angular 2 service which I use to capture changes to some inputs in a component, and using a BehaviorSubject, pass to another component. Because I want to compare the current values to the last values, I was thinking to use bufferCount as per another SO question and pass that to filter. Unfortunately, the behavior I'm getting out of bufferCount is a bit baffling, and I can't tell if I'm doing observables wrong.

My service is pretty straight forward: instantiate a BehaviorSubject, one function to advance the value, one function to return the observable:

```
export class EventFilterService {
    private filtersSubject: BehaviorSubject<Object>;

    constructor() {
        this.filtersSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({
            search: '',
            types: [],
            dates: []
        });
    }

    setFilters(filters: {}) {
        this.filtersSubject.next(filters);
    }

    getFilters() {
        return this.filtersSubject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

In my component with the inputs, I simply pass the updated value to setFilters on a click event. In the component where I need the data, I setup an ngOnInit to setup the subscriptions:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.eventFilterService.getFilters().bufferCount(2, 1).filter((val:[{}]) => {
        console.log(val[0]['types'] == val[1]['types']);
        return true; 
    }).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
    this.eventFilterService.getFilters().debounceTime(2500).subscribe((filters) => {
        console.log(filters);
        this.filters = filters;
        this.eventService.getEvents(this.filters).subscribe((data: Event[]) => { this.processEvents(data); });
    });
}
```

However, the results are weird. On load, I get a blank filter object, as expected. The first time the filters change, the buffer gives me the last value as a blank object and the current value as whatever is selected. However, on every change thereafter, the buffer returns me two identical values (the previous state being the same as the current state, which is correct). Logging the click event, I see it's only hit once and the service's `setFilters` method is only called once.

Is this a case of me not understanding how bufferCount works? Poor design on my part?

Here is a [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/UFRNfgaPuNKfozDzX5iI) showing the behavior I'm pushing. Keep your console open to see what I mean.

Comment: Can you make a minimal testcase on plunkr/jsbin/jsfiddle/... ? Given the code I don't see exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Added a plunkr link to the question.